# Application of Maschke's Theorem to $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm trying to find something out about an algebraically closed field $k$ with char $k \notin \{2,3\}$. (Specifically, the number of irreducible $k$-linear representations of $S_4$.)
Now I no little of ring theory, and nothing about field theory. My guess however is that I can treat $k$ as if it were $\mathbb{C}$, as follows:

The divisors of $S_4$ are 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24. As the number of irreducible representations equals the number of conjugacy classes, and the number of conjugacy classes equals the number of simple $k[G]$-modules (up to isomorphism), 
by Maschke's Theorem, we are looking for $k[G]$-modules for which char $k \nmid \#G = 24$. Now (and here's where I'm bluffing) the other divisors (besides 2 and 3) are excluded because they are not prime, so that only leaves char $k = 0$, so $k \cong \mathbb{C}$...?

**Edit**

In my proof I make use of the set of class functions 
$$\mathbb{C}_{\text{class}}(S_4) = \{f : S_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \mid (\forall \sigma, \tau \in S_4)(f(\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}) = f(\tau))\}.$$

Would it be enough to generalise this to $k_{\text{class}}(S_4)$ for the given $k$. 
If so, how would one go about this?

Comment: The characteristic of a field is prime. So excluding $2$ and $3$ is enough, but it in no way implies characteristic $0$.

Comment: There are also algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ that are not isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, such as the field of algebraic numbers, or an algebraic closure of a field of rational functions.

Comment: @MattSamuel, aren't there fields of prime _power_ characteristic?

Comment: No, there are fields of prime power order, but their characteristic is the base prime. An algebraically closed field is infinite anyway.